# iOS: Difficulty the correct selected row of an indexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on an app with a hierarchy of TableViewControllers. Selecting the first choice brings up a specific sub-table, which works just fine. Selecting the row in the sub-table should bring up a specific view with content. The code for the second segue is as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showUSViewDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        USDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSString *currentSelection = [NSString new];
        currentSelection = [examDetailViewContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.usView = [views objectForKey:currentSelection];
    }
}
```

examDetailViewContents is the array that is used to populate the contents of the TableView in the sub-table, and the usView is a variable that contains the data for the content view that gets pulled up with the selection.

The problem is that regardless of which row is selected, it always acts as if the first row is selected (interestingly, the data is passed and the content displays perfectly, only it's just the content tagged to the first row of the table). What I really don't understand is that I used essentially the same code for the segue from the first table to the sub-table, and it works perfectly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: print the currentSelection string and see whether you are getting it right?

Comment: You have a debugger. Debug!

Comment: Unrelated - calling `[NSString new];` is pointless in your code. Just do: `NSString *currentSelection = [examDetailViewContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`.

Comment: Printing currentSelection just prints out the text on the first row of the table regardless of which row I select.